# Internet Explorer(IE11) not opening basic authentication window

Tags: windows, authentication, internet-explorer-11, basic-authentication, http-authentication

Tested on a few other computers, the basic authentication is definitely working on IE11 for other computers.  However, on my computer, I can't seem to get a username/password to prompt for IE11. It does work on all the other browsers installed on the computer.

I've tried reinstalling IE11, deleting all sorts of cache/credentials, changing various internet security levels, changing User Authentication to "Prompt for user name and password" on each zone.  I've also tried in private browsing.

I have a feeling it's either a windows setting or an IE11 setting at this point.  Any direction would be wonderful.

IE11 Version: 11.836.18362.0

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what settings you have modified in the IE 11 browser so first I suggest you reset the IE browser.

After that set Logon option to **Prompt for user name and password** for the desires zone.

If you are trying to authenticate with a different origin then enabled the **Access data sources across domains** under Miscellaneous category.

Let us know, whether it helps to fix this issue or not.

If the issue persists then try to provide more detailed information. Like which OS build you are using and information about the site.

Comment: Tried both of those - did not have an effect.  

Windows 10 Pro - 18363.836

Comment: Did you see any difference in the update version or difference in the settings of the problematic machine and the machines that are working fine? For testing purposes, Go to these 2 locations in the registry editor HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_HTTP_USERNAME_PASSWORD_DISABLE
and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MAIN\FeatureControl\FEATURE_HTTP_USERNAME_PASSWORD_DISABLE Create Dword 32 bit key with 'iexplore.exe' and 'explorer.exe' Set its value as 0. See if it works.

Comment: No differences in versions/settings that I can see.  Did the above, did not see any difference - restarted after changes to confirm check.

Comment: Could the pop up window be hidden in some capacity? I know I had an issue pulling the inspector up a few months ago.

Comment: I tried to check the update history of 18363.836 update. I noticed that there are some updates to improve security when using Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge and updates for verifying usernames and passwords. Ref: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4556799/windows-10-update-kb4556799 I am not sure whether there is some issue with this update as I did not get any document that mentions this issue with this update. I suggest you try to provide the feedback from the IE browser to Microsoft about this issue. Thanks for your understanding.